# field in my oracle database which is of "DATE" and other field which is of type "TIMESTAMP"

Tags: date, oracle-sqldeveloper

i have a field in my oracle database which is of "DATE" and other field which is of type "TIMESTAMP"..
When i write a select query to retrieve these fields from plsqldeveloper the output is of the format

```
"05-11-16"
```

however when i retrieve the same data from my java code (spring data jpa) the output is of the format

```
"2005-02-10 00:00:00"
```

can someone help me to understand what is the reason for this discrepancy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's your NLS Format settings that are probably influencing the way the output is being displayed.

```
SELECT *
  FROM sys.nls_session_parameters
 WHERE parameter LIKE '%FORMAT%';

SELECT sysdate,
       systimestamp
  FROM dual;
```

Gives me this...

```
PARAMETER                      VALUE                                                           
------------------------------ ----------------------------------------------------------------
NLS_DATE_FORMAT                DD-MON-RR  HH24.MI.SS                                           
NLS_TIME_FORMAT                HH.MI.SSXFF AM                                                  
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT           DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM                                        
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT             HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR                                              
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT        DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR                                    


SYSDATE             SYSTIMESTAMP                          
------------------- --------------------------------------
08-JUL-19  09.34.04 08-JUL-19 09.34.04.878569000 AM -04:00
```

If you care about how your DATE or TIMESTAMP values are formatted, build it into your query.

[image]

Comment: can i force the oracle to store the date in DD-MM-YYYY format? i want that date format (i get when i query DB) from javacode should be of format DD-MM-YYYY.

Comment: what you're asking to do is to store the DATE as a string - and yes, you can do that, convert the column to VARCHAR2 - but then you will lose ALL the DATE functionality the database gives you. We don't store dates in any format like what you're asking. You tell us how you want the dates displayed when you query them out. Put the date format into your javacode (either by setting the nls_date_format for your session or by changing your queries like i showed above)